# Tracing a text message

Tags: mobile

Good afternoon,
Is there anyway to trace a text message? As far as the real phone number that the text is being sent from? Or the location of where the text is being sent from?

I've been getting harassing text messages from someone and when I try to call the phone number back I am getting an automated voice mail (does not seem to be legit) I contacted my cell phone provider but they are unable to give me that information.

Comment: I would just block the number, it's unlikely the police will take an interest unless theres a knife wielding maniac following you around in person :3

Comment: If it is at all possible that they are ignoring your number on the phone you can also spoof your number through proxy.

Check this site out: http://www.telespoof.com/freecall/agi

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, there's no way for an end user to trace that information. Your cell phone provider should at least be able to trace it back to the SMSC that it was sent from, however they are unlikely to do so without some sort of police request or court order.

If you are being threatened or genuinely harassed then get the police involved, they have the power to compel the phone company to research that. It's their job to deal with these types of things after all. If it's an annoyance you can almost certainly just set up a block of that number on your phone.